# issue with onKeyDown functionality in react app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I am new to React and creating a calculator app with React-Redux to gain knowledge of the framework.
The app is working with the onClick event but some issues are there. I have created a sandbox for anyone to see.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-dezmon

While doing my Calculator app, I am facing 2 challenges.

1. onKeyDown not working. Basically I want the same functionality as it is happening in the onClick event (which is working fine).
2. After any operation (after clicking '='), when I click on any other digit, the previous state is not clearing. For eg, if I add 52 + 6, after clicking = when I click on any digit(2 for eg) it is picking as 62. It should clear basically.

Any help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use `onKeyDown` directly on your `<Digits>` because the event only fires when the element is currently focused and only 1 element can be focused at a time in a page.

What you need to do is to move your `onKeyDown` to the parent, and put this listener on the parent element.

Therefore the way you should handle the event is to parse which key on keyboard is being tapped, then run your operation based on that information.

See it here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-pmmntj